# JavaFx TableView with old TableModel

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jtable, tableview

I have a Swing application with many JTables that I want to migrate to JavaFX.
My biggest headache is JTable.

I it possible to fill data in a JavaFX TableView without ObservableList?

I understand that the Observable concept has many cool features but I can live without them to easily go away from JTable.

I fill the data in JTable by inheriting javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel and want to somehow use same concept in a TableView or any  other JavaFX control.

The data is stored in CachedRowSet and I don't want to store the data both in ObservableList and CachedRowSet. CachedRowSet is used to persist data back to the Database.

Thanks,
Hugo

Comment: `tableView.getItems().setAll(normalList);`. Of course, further modification has to be done directly on `tableView.getItems()` (which is an `ObservableList`).

Comment: no, it's not possible to use tableView without providing the data as observableList - the sooner you start exposing your data as such the better :)

Comment: Forgot to mention that the data is stored in CachedRowSet and I don't want to store the data both in  ObservableList and CachedRowSet.
CachedRowSet is used to persist data back to the Database.

Comment: to put it bluntly: it doesn't matter what you _want_ or not - you either follow the fx winds of doing stuff or use a different framework or write your own, there is no lee-way: the only "model" a tableView knows to handle is an ObservableList - you __MUST__ present your data as such (or leave it, see earlier in this comment ;)